# How to use google font

Tags: css, google-font-api

i want to use myriad web pro from Google font. i used this code for that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=myriad+web+pro">
```

and use css code for that

```
font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "Segoe UI", "Verdana", "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

but myriad web pro is not applied. how i solve this problem

Comment: Look at the stylesheet you are using. It consists solely of a comment: `/* Not supported. */`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Myriad isn't a Google Web Font. You have to choose one [they actually offer](http://www.google.com/webfonts), or use [TypeKit](https://typekit.com/fonts/myriad-pro), which offers Myriad Pro (for a yearly fee).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah like he said That sadly isn't a Google Font, however don't worry because there is a font that is very similar: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/PT+Sans